# Topological embeddings of real projective space in euclidean space

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I was wondering whether the real projective space $\Bbb{R}P^n$ embeds *topologically* into  $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ for odd $n$.

It certainly doesn't for even $n$ because of Alexander duality. Also it doesn't embed *smoothly* for any $n$. I will prove the two above statements in my algebraic topological class, but I couldn't find anything in the literature for topological embeddings in the odd case.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're not assuming any nice behavior, eg locally flat, for your embedding. Right?

Comment: If you restrict to locally flat embeddings, it looks like you can rule out $\mathbb{RP}^{4k-1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4k}$.

Comment: The arguments that obstruct a smooth embedding will also obstruct the existence of a locally flat embedding. Put differently, by topological embedding I mean an injective continuous map (that is a homeomorphism onto its image).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true that all real projective space $RP^n$ can not be smoothly embedded in $R^{n+1}$ for n >1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96583/is-it-true-that-all-real-projective-space-rpn-can-not-be-smoothly-embedded-in)

Comment: It is essentially a duplicate of an earlier question which was about smooth embeddings but the proof did not use smoothness.

Comment: as I say below, I am not convinced that the other argument does not use smoothness. The argument says that S^{n+1} minus RP^n consists of two path-connected components whose closures we denote by A and B. But why should there be a Mayer-Vietoris  sequence for $S^{n+1} = A \cup B $?

Comment: @StefanFriedl: incidentally, I disagree with your statement "the arguments that obstruct a smooth embedding will also obstruct the existence of a locally flat embedding". There is a large body of works in homotopy theory (related to the study of vector fields on spheres) that give obstructions to smooth embeddings but it says nothing (as far as I can see) about locally flat embeddings. See references in http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/immtable for the smooth case.

Comment: To expand on my comment: Brown proved in http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970177 that any locally flat submanifold of a sphere is bi-collared but I do not see why this implies it is smoothable.

Comment: What I meant is, that if you have a locally flat embedding of $\Bbb{R}P^n$ into $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ you get a collar, which then allows you to do the Mayer-Vietoris argument with singular cohomology instead of Alexander-Spanier cohomology. But this logic works in this particular codimension one problem. I am not making any more general comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first page of W.~Massey's paper [On the imbeddability of the real projective spaces in Euclidean space](https://msp.org/pjm/1959/9-3/pjm-v9-n3-p17-p.pdf) states that $\mathbb RP^n$ with $n>1$ cannot be imbedded topologically in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ because its mod $2$ cohomology algebra does not satisfy a certain condition given by R. Thom.

The reference points to Theorem V.15 (p.180) of Thom's paper  
[Espaces fibrés en sphères et carrés de Steenrod,](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1952_3_69__109_0.pdf)
Annales scientifiques de l'École Normale Supérieure, Série 3 : Volume 69 (1952) , p. 109-182.

EDIT: Actually, a proof can be found in [Is it true that all real projective space $RP^n$ can not be smoothly embedded in $R^{n+1}$ for n >1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96583/is-it-true-that-all-real-projective-space-rpn-can-not-be-smoothly-embedded-in).

Comment: The paper by Thom seems to answer my question. It's slightly unfortunate that Thom doesn't explain what he means by "plonge", but since he distinguishes between "plonge" and "plonge differentiablement" it seems like he means a topological embedding.

Comment: The reference to the other mathoverflow discussion is nice. But I don't see how it applies in the topological case. To make the Meyer-Vietoris argument work you need some type of regularity, isn't it? (So I am a little confused by the comment in that discussion that the argument is precisely the one that Thom gave).

Comment: @StefanFriedl: Mayer-Vietoris sequence works for excisive triads. The solution is to use a fancier cohomology theory, e.g. if $A$, $B$, are closed subsets of the compact Hausdorff space $X$, then the triad $(X,A,B)$ is excisive for the Alexander-Spanier cohomology, see Theorem 8.14, Chapter II, section 8 in a book by W.Massey [Homology and cohomology theory, 1978]. In our case $X=S^{2n}$ and $A$, $B$ are closures of the components of $S^{2n}\setminus\mathbb RP^{2n-1}$. The linked argument is a formal consequence of the Mayer-Vietoris so it applies.

Comment: The argument will also need the Alexander duality for the Alexander-Spanier cohomology $H^*$, which can be found in the same Massey's book. Thus $H^{2n}(A)=0=H^{2n}(B)$ with mod $2$ coefficients.

Comment: I just noticed that Thom in the above-linked paper uses the Alexander-Spanier cohomology, which is why he can apply Mayer-Vietoris. For singular cohomology the triad in question might be not excisive.

Comment: great, thanks! Even though I don't understand all details I can now see that there's an argument. It's exactly what I was looking for, I was fairly sure that you can not embed $RP^{n-1}$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, but I was also fairly sure that one needed some extra ingredient beyond Alexander duality and the usual smooth argument.